# An issue in adjusted_rand_score function: overflow encountered in longlong_scalars (tp + fp) * (fp + tn))

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, cluster-computing

I'm using `adjusted_rand_score` to calculate ARI of two labelset in python and meet this overflow issue.

I print out the table where `Aij=(label1==i&label2==j)` and sort it. It looks as follows.

```
[[23356.    21.    10.    13.     3.     0.]
 [   30.  8892.  1106.    86.    25.     1.]
 [ 2817.  3476.  7138.  1981.  1780.  4487.]
 [   31.    55.  1038.  5225.    64.   845.]
 [   58.   861.  2261.   215.  2391.   336.]
 [10989.    63.   111.    40.     9.    62.]]
```

I know it is because of some number is too large to handle in longlong_scalars, But I don't know how to resolve this issue.

labelA is generated like this

```
data_raw=pd.read_csv('recon.csv',header=0,index_col=0)
data_test=data_raw.to_numpy()[:,1:982]
print(data_test.shape)
cluster,label=kmeans(data_test,k=7) #label will be a numpy array
```

label b is the baseline of the form of a string type

```
gt = pd.read_csv('nano_gt.csv', header=0, index_col=0)
print(gt['merge_cell_type'])
```

Output is:

```
tumors             37281
fibroblast         13368
lymphocyte         11664
Mcell               7560
neutrophil          5731
endothelial         4272
```

And I then apply `adjusted_rand_score` to these two labels and report the following.
And it also return a negative number.
But the same code runs well in another desktop, so I don't know what happened to my code.

```
E:\Users\.....\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\cluster\_supervised.py:390: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in longlong_scalars
  (tp + fp) * (fp + tn))
```

Comment: None of those will produce an overflow when multiplied.  Show us your code, please.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The code is attached, I think it is very trivial code